# Spring security supperpassword

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Good day, guys.

I use Spring MVC with Spring security in my project. http://my-fin.ru
Often I need to login as one of my users and chek out its problems. So I need to have a password, which would allow me to login with any login. 
Some kind of "superpassword" which fit any of my users login.

Is it possible with spring security?

Thank you.

Comment: No you don't. What you want is some functionality that you can become that user, i.e. Switch User functionality which Spring Security supports out of the box. See http://java.dzone.com/articles/su-and-sudo-spring-security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Super User Password or something, but Spring Security provides a way to switch the user (of course you have to configure it).

The Spring Security way is the [SwitchUserFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.html)

@See [NoBlogDevFound: su and sudo in Spring Security applications](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.de/2013/06/su-and-sudo-in-spring-security.html) blog for an example